# ${L^*}$ the Kleene star language is decidable then is $ {L}$ decidable

Tags: turing-machines, undecidability, decision-problem

let ${L^*}$  be the  Kleene star language which  is definded like that :
$${L^*}=\{w_1,w_2, \dots ,w_n\mid n \geq0   \text{ and each $w_i \in L$}\}$$

I have to  show of this  correct or not !
$$ {L^*} \text{is decidable } \Rightarrow {L}  \text{ is decidable} $$

$\textbf{my idea was  to use the reduction function }$

let $f_k$ a calculatable function ; 
$$ f_k :{L} \rightarrow {L^*}$$
$$w \mapsto w_1w_2\dots w_k \text{ with  each $w_i =w \text{ for all i}\in [1,k]$ }$$ 
$$ \text{for all w $\in{L}$} \Leftrightarrow f_k(w)= w_1w_2\dots w_k \in{L^*} $$
then  we have  ; 
$$\text{for all w $\in{L}$} \Leftrightarrow  f_k(w) \in {L^*} \Rightarrow {L}\leq {L^*} \rightarrow {L} \text{ is decidable}$$

$\textbf{Is that correct ? }$

Comment: related: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/84197

Answer (score 1):

$w\in L$ indeed implies that $f_k(w)\in L^*$, where $f_k(w)$ consists of $k$ copies of $w$. But how do you obtain the opposite implication? You might be able to decompose $f_k(w)$ into words in $L$, while $w\notin L$.

In general, the implication is not true. Think about what happens when $L$ contains every singleton from the alphabet.

Comment: i don t get the point  ,  so you mean that  i have to contruct  $f_k$ again so that the  other  direction  of the implication  must be true ? and if i understand correct  is not  each  decompostion of  w in ${L^*}$ can be in L ,right . ?

Comment: I showed that your reduction does not work, since you have only proved one direction. The statement in the title of your question is false, see the hint in the second part of my answer.

Comment: can you   give  an example for that  ?

Comment: so  you mean like when  ${L}=\{0,1\}$

Comment: I think a hint will do for now, you can now come up with a contradicting example on your own.

Comment: so i know  that  ${L }\subset {L^*}=\{0,1\}^*$ and i know  that {L^*} in that  case  decidable and  i know there exist languages as subset from {L^*} which are not  decidable  which  implies  that my statement in the tittle of my question is not always  true  . is that correct ?